# Google API KEY referral wildcard for localhost development

Tags: google-maps, google-api, wildcard, api-key

Google advises to specify which domains the browser key is allowed to be used from.

[image]

While this is definitely a great feature, I would like for the key to keep working while I'm developing the website on `localhost`.

I guess one sure way is to just not specify an API_KEY at all in development environment (google maps work locally without it).

Still this is not always convenient.

I would like to find out exactly what is the correct way to specify the wildcard for the key to work locally.

I have achieved this before by defining a whole bunch of wildcards in hopes that one of them would work. And, well, some of them did, because it worked eventually.

Since google says it takes for about 5 minutes for the referral changes to take effect I had never had the patience to find out which card exactly had done the job.

And google doesn't provide any visuals as to which card would match what domains.

[Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-api/Q5wGjM4zzhY) someone says that `API_KEY` works for `localhost/` by default. But of course I have my local server at some port other than `:80`. In this case that person suggests to specify the wildcard with the `port` like this: `http://localhost:1234`.

This is very undesired. If I change the port I'm working I surely won't remember that some `API_KEY` relies on it.

So... what is the correct way to specify a referral for localhost for **any port**?

`localhost:*` ?

`localhost:*/*` ?

`*localhost:*` ?

`http://localhost:*` ?

`localhost\:*` ?

...Does someone *know*?

---

Another thing which might be obvious for some but... I'm not sure.
Does a wildcard `*.example.com/*` authorize the url of type `http://example.com/some/long/path/`?

Comment: There is no point to add `regex` tag to this question, it is written - **wildcards**. They are not regex.

Comment: I had a thought that maybe the colon `:` needs to be escaped. Are we sure that google doesn't interpret a regular expression if it is entered?

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no wildcard for port, so don't use it. Simply omit any reference to port and you should be fine.

I'm using a Cordova Meteor app that embeds a web server (for local storage) running on localhost with a random port assigned by Meteor at runtime. There is no way to know what port Cordova will pick up and on any instance (device running the app) can be a different one.

I've tried many variations like `localhost:*` or `localhost:*/*` to no avail.

Eventually I tried a simple `localhost` and it worked. Now all my requests to `http://localhost:<SOME_RANDOM_PORT>/<SOME_RANDOM_PATH>` work.

So, go to Google API Manager - Credentials - API key - in the "Accept requests from these HTTP referrers (web sites)" enter `localhost` and hit Save.

Just a note. This solution whitelists all requests on localhost on any path. You can't add anything after the `localhost` entry as that seems to brake the rule.

Answer (score 0):

**Google API KEY referral wildcard for localhost development..does anyone know?**

This is easy. You need to register the URL origin in GDC for you to develop locally. Make sure to include the port number as well. This looks like

```
http://localhost:8080
```

Assuming you have Python installed in your computer, go to terminal and start your server by typing:

```
//Assuming you're using http://localhost:8080 as URL origin
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

When the server is running, you can now use it to run your maps locally like:

```
//assuming file is in Desktop.
http://localhost:8080/SimpleMap.html
```

There you go.

Comment: Well, thanks! But the question was specifically about finding a way to *not* be dependent on a certain port number. I'm running my development server on port `8000` currently, but I might change that in the future. I wish to not have to change the wildcard of some API. I wish that the wildcard could allow for any port number.

Comment: I don't know if the feature you're asking exists. Good luck

Comment: Changing ports is easy, you just need to reconfigure it. Though, you have to do it manually each time, the process doesn't even take a minute.

Comment: I think I left a comment but it disappeared. I said the problem wasn't that changing the local server port was hard, it's that it's definitely going to be hard to remember to change the settings of some API somewhere in case I do change the port number. This is a noticeable inconvenience. Especially if the project lives long enough to change the developers working on it. Maybe leaving a comment note works, but that's far from the best solution, too.